# I'm having trouble spacing a menu control in an ASP.NET page. Is my solution the correct way to do this?

Tags: asp.net

Hey, I added a menu control to my page that is displayed vertically. I couldn't find a way to add spaces (I'd like about 5px.) between the menu items, so I just did something similar to this:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="ActiveBorder">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="One" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>

<p></p>

<asp:Menu ID="Menu2" runat="server" BackColor="ActiveBorder">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Two" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

I just created multiple menu controls with a single menu item control in them, and placed a break between the menu controls. This seems very wrong to me, but I could not figure out another way. Also, this is a bit off subject, but is it okay to use empty paragraph tags as line breaks?(sometimes a br tag is too much) Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Add the `RenderingMode="Table"` property into the Menu.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class in your CSS file for your menu formatting and assign the margin and/or padding there, then you can assign the class in your menu tag. This will help you avoid using unnecessary markup just for spacing sake.

CSS File:

```
.menuItem { margin-top:5px;}
```

aspx markup:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menuItem" BackColor="ActiveBorder">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="One" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Cool, this makes more sense for controlling the spacing between menuItems. But, is there a way to have spacing between MenuItems using only one Menu control, as opposed to the way I did it, by creating multiple Menu controls with only one MenuItem control in it? Thanks...

Comment: I'm not sure what markup the menu control creates, but you can view the page source and design your CSS around that.  Also check out this link for styling your menu http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366731.aspx

Comment: also check out Firebug if you're not using it and you can tweak the style on the fly and get a good idea of what you should put in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to use a br tag instead of a p tag, but that may just be my own personal eccentricities... but if you really want to control the spacing, you might want to consider a div between each menu item that has some custom set height.  Then you get to choose exactly how far apart each menu item is spaced.